# Clear Search on Semantic-ui

Tags: search, semantic-ui

How do I get the selected result of a search field of `Semantic-UI`?

Using `onSelect` event, I can get the selected result, but this does not work when clean the field with the backspace.

Using  `field.search('get result')` also not return the result blank as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected result like this:

```
onSelect:function(result){ 
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of your Answer by explaining why the Questioner's approach was failing and why / how your Answer fixes the problem.  Please remember to include links to any sources you find useful in explaining your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having a sample HTML form with 2 inputs like this (one hidden):

```
<form id="search-box-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="" />
    <div class="ui search location-search">
        <div class="ui icon input">
            <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search locations..." />
            <i class="search icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="results"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The same way you use `onSelect` to populate your hidden field, you can use `onResultsClose` to clear your hidden input. Caveat: `onResultsClose` will run before semantic puts the value on it's own field, hence the need to use timeout function.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(
            function() {
                jQuery('.location-search')
                    .search({
                        source : content,
                        searchOnFocus : true,
                        minCharacters : 0,
                        onSelect: function(result, response) {
                            var value = result.value;
                            $('#search-box-form').find('input[name=search]').val(value);
                        },
                        onResultsClose: function(){
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                if (jQuery('.location-search').search('get value') == '') {
                                    $('#search-box-form').find('input[name=search]').val('');
                                }
                            }, 500);

                        }
                    })
                ;
            }
        );
```